# Using powershell reflection to perform database updates

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm editing my question to make it more readily understood.

Here is an example solution: https://github.com/mckenn55/PowershellTest

I created a brand new net47 MVC project.  I added an area called "Database" and a controller within that area called "Update".  Within that controller, I have the following:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Execute());
    }

    public static List<string> Execute()
    {
        var returnable = new List<string>();

        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        string codeBase = assembly.CodeBase;
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
        var assemblyLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

        string resourcePath = "";

        string ModuleName = assembly.ManifestModule.Name;
        ModuleName = ModuleName.Substring(0, ModuleName.LastIndexOf("."));
        ModuleName = ModuleName.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", "");

        string FolderPath = "Areas.Database.SQL";
        FolderPath = FolderPath.Replace(' ', '_');

        if (FolderPath != null && FolderPath.Length > 0 && FolderPath[FolderPath.Length - 1] == '.')
            FolderPath = FolderPath.Substring(0, FolderPath.Length - 1);

        StringBuilder filepath = new StringBuilder();
        filepath.Append(ModuleName);
        if (FolderPath != null && FolderPath.Length > 0)
        {
            filepath.Append('.' + FolderPath);
            filepath.Append('.');
        }
        resourcePath = filepath.ToString();

        string[] resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
        foreach (var resourceName in resourceNames)
        {
            if (Regex.Match(resourceName, "^" + resourcePath).Success)
            {
                returnable.Add(resourceName);
            }
        }

        var orderedFileNames = new List<string>();
        if (returnable != null && returnable.Any())
        {
            orderedFileNames = returnable.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            returnable.Add("No files found");
        }

        return returnable;
    }
```

Within the Database area, I have a directory called "SQL" and within that directory, I have a single file, TestFile.sql, included in the solution as an embedded resource.  The results of the Execute() method, when viewed using the index action is "PSTest.Areas.Database.SQL.TestFile.sql".  I would like to see the same thing in Powershell.  I have tried the following:

```
> Add-Type -path "C:\Temp\PSTest\PSTest\bin\PSTest.dll"
> [PSTest.Areas.Database.UpdateController]::Execute()
No Files Found
```

Is my goal possible through powershell and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a solution to this using powershell alone.  I wrote a C# console app that is able to perform these actions without any issue.